# How to change color of just the bottom side of the border of raised button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, colors

How to change color of just one side of the border of a raised button in flutter?
[image]

Comment: Which side of which border?

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan Those Day01, Day02 you see there are raised buttons, I want the bottom side to have a yellow color and rest of the border sides to be transprent

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your raised button within a container. And give

```
Container(
decoration : BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(
               width:3,
               color : Colors.yellow
         ),
      ),
      child:RaisedButton()
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
...
DecoratedBox(
decoration:const BoxDecoration(
border: Border(
bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
),
),
child: ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () { },
child:const Text('Button'),
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
elevation: 0,
primary: Colors.white,
onPrimary: Colors.black
),
),
),
...
[image]